# Can GSON use LinkedList as the default deserialization for the java.util.List interface?

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list, deserialization, gson

When GSON deserializes a field in a class that has the type java.util.List, it seems to favor ArrayList as the list implementation to use. Is there any way to default it to use LinkedList (other than actually defining that as the type of the field)?

Comment: it may not be super important in this specific example, but if you have some field that is declared as an interface, it would be nice to know that GSON can let you switch between default implementations.

In this case, I am setting most of my lists to LinkedLists to make JVM memory allocation easier. However, when I serialized the object I noticed that it was an ArrayList. I could declare it explicitly, but was mostly curious if GSON supported this feature.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is No!
But still you can use this construction:

```
LinkedList<Foo> list = new LinkedList<>(
    (ArrayList<Foo>) new Gson().fromJson(
        gsonString, new TypeToken<List<Foo>>(){}.getType()
    )
);
```